# Button not showing

Tags: java, android

I am trying to design a menubar. Everything is working fine, except the 3rd item is not showing at all. I even tried to specify that button is visible and still no success.

Code here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@color/lists_background_grey"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/menuBox"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_bar_menu" />
        <!--        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>-->




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HeaderName"
        android:layout_width="275sp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingEnd="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cart"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_cart2"
        />



</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is no space for the second button, because you have hardcoded width. I suggest to replace it with this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                                   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                   android:background="@color/lists_background_grey"
                                   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                   android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                                   app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/menuBox"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_bar_menu"
            />
        <!--        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>-->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/HeaderName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingEnd="50dp"
            android:paddingRight="50dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cart"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_cart2"
            />

    </LinearLayout >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar >
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented your xml code, That is ok and the button is visible. I think maybe there is a problem with your button background. Change it to a color to see its visibility.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/cart"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    />
```